# Is there an analog for scipy.optimize.least_squares in Julia?

Tags: optimization, julia, least-squares, minimization

I'm trying to rewrite some Python code i have in Julia to check if it will be faster and got stuck at some point.

In Python i have this code to calculate a kind of center for some points:

```python
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
import numpy as np

def lat_lng_dist(lat, lng, _lat, _lng):
    # calc distance between point (lat, lng) and points
    return # array with distances

def lat_lng_metric_MAE(point, _lat, _lng, _radius):
    lat, lng = point
    modules = np.abs(lat_lng_dist(lat, lng, _lat, _lng) - _radius)
    return np.mean(modules)

def predict_center(init_point, data):
    return least_squares(lat_lng_metric_MAE, x0=init_point, loss='cauchy', \
                         args=(data['lat'].values, data['lng'].values, data['radius'].values, ))
```

Is there a drop in replacement for Julia?
Or maybe point me on how to get same result with packages like LsqFit and others, spent half a day on this, find some similar, but can't understand how to adopt them.

Comment: Not my area, but rhe packages mentioned on https://juliapackages.com/p/leastsquaresoptim might be of interest

Answer (score 1):

Well, I didn't find a direct replacement and this part is quite small compared to the whole program, so I used PyCall for this, hoping scipy is more or less fast, and now the code looks like this:

```
using PyCall
optimize = pyimport("scipy.optimize")

py"""
import numpy as np

def lat_lng_dist(lat, lng, _lat, _lng):
    d_s_lat = np.square(np.sin(np.deg2rad((lat - _lat) / 2)))
    d_s_lng = np.square(np.sin(np.deg2rad((lng - _lng) / 2)))
    return 2 * np.float64(6371008.8) * np.arcsin(
        np.sqrt(d_s_lat + np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat)) * np.cos(np.deg2rad(_lat)) * d_s_lng))

def lat_lng_metric_MAE(point, _lat, _lng, _radius):
    lat, lng = point
    modules = np.abs(lat_lng_dist(lat, lng, _lat, _lng) - _radius)
    return np.mean(modules )
"""

function predict_center(init_point, data)
    return optimize.least_squares(py"lat_lng_metric_MAE", x0=init_point, loss="cauchy", args=(data.lat, data.lng, data.radius))
end
```

I don't know how this performs, but in overall I got program running ~50 times faster and I'm happy with it.
But still would highly appreciate if someone could help to translate it to native Julia code.